# Is the prophet "like moses" in Deut 18 always understood specifically not in the sense of the "prophet like Moses" in Deut 34:10?

Tags: tanach, moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash

Is the prophet "like moses" in  Deut 18 always understood specifically not in the sense of  the "prophet like Moses" in Deut 34:10?

Deut 18:18 "נָבִיא אָקִים לָהֶם מִקֶּרֶב אֲחֵיהֶם, כָּמוֹךָ"  "I will raise them up a prophet from among their brethren, like unto thee........"

Deut 34:10  וְלֹא-קָם נָבִיא עוֹד בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל כְּמֹשֶׁה אֲשֶׁר יְדָעוֹ יְהוָה פָּנִים אֶל-פָּנִים   "And there hath not arisen a prophet since in Israel like unto Moses, whom the LORD knew face to face;"

Do those that say that Deut 18:18 refers to Joshua or that it's a general statement about prophets, have to read it such that when Deut 18 says "like you"/"like me", it doesn't mean it in the sense of Deut 34:10 "The LORD knew face to face"?

And if any do read it in the context of Deut 34:10, do they have to say it's Messianic? (since if Deut 18 is understood to be saying The LORD will raise up a prophet like Moses, by which it means whom the LORD knows face to face, then, that still hasn't happened yet so would have to be a Messianic thing.

I haven't heard of it being a Messianic reference, so then do the commentators take Deut 18's reference to a prophet like Moses to be understood specifically not in the "like Moses" sense stated in Deut 34:10?

I suppose Deut 34:10 could be read as implying that Deut 18 has not yet been fulfilled? (Since Deut 18 speaks of a prophet like Moses that will arise at a future time, and Deut 34:10 says no prophet like Moses has arisen...). So Deut 34:10 might be connecting to Deut 18, when it talks of a prophet like Moses.

Comment: The simile "like" does not mean similar in every way, just one way: that the prophets will be Jewish.

Comment: @N.T. Nobody is suggesting that "like" means "every way", that'd make no sense. But you obviously think "like" doesn't mean like the like in Deut 34:10